# How do I compile sass directly to the css file on the web host?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, media-queries

I was wondering if its possible to edit SCSS codes locally and have gulp compile the final css code into a css file on the server?
I made a website for a customer a while ago and now they want me to make some changes that messes up the responsiveness, I used css media query to do it before and now I have to edit some of it ,the problem is the back-end language is C#.net and I don't have access to it so unfortunately I can't have a local setup ergo no preview.
It would be very helpful to also know your approach in this situation.

I hope my question is clear, English is not my first language so please forgive my mistakes.
If you need more information please let me know in the comments
Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Why you need to edit SCSS on server. You can directly edit compiled css file. No need to compile then.

Comment: With what program can you send the files to the server, `ftp`, `sftp`, `scp` etc? Depending on the program, there are good modules for gulp that can transfer files with the wanted protocol.

Comment: @lofihelsinki Yes I have access to ftp but can gulp edit a file on server? and do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: You can upload files with ftp in Gulp using [vinyl-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp). It doesn't really edit the files on the server, but rather compiles them locally and then sends them to the server. But that should work and i think it's fine as an idea.

Comment: @lofihelsinki Thank you